# Pandas - Finding percent contributed by each group

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find the percentage contribution made by each date group. Given below is how my data looks like.

Expecting to find contribution of each product for a given date.

```
date, product, quantity
2020-01, prod_a, 100
2020-01, prod_b, 200
2020-01, prod_c, 20
2020-01, prod_d, 50
2020-02, prod_a, 30
2020-02, prod_b, 30
2020-02, prod_c, 40
```

My expected output would be as below:

```
date, product, quantity, prct_contributed
2020-01, prod_a, 100, 27%
2020-01, prod_b, 200, 54%
2020-01, prod_c, 20, 5%
2020-01, prod_d, 50, 14%
2020-02, prod_a, 30, 30%
2020-02, prod_b, 30, 30%
2020-02, prod_c, 40, 40%
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby().transform()`:

```
df['quantity'] / df.groupby('date')['quantity'].transform('sum')
```